# Validar el rut con inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alguien sabe como puedo determinar que mi rut sea 12.345.678-9 o 12.345.678-k utilizando este código y que incluya los puntos entre los números

```
$("#rut").inputmask('Regex', {regex: "[0-9-.Kk]{10}"});
```

Comment: Como sugerencia, recuerda siempre que este sitio lo leen personas de varios países y el RUT no es un término común a todos.

Answer (score 3):

Para formatear RUT en jQuery con el Inputmask de [RobinHerbots/Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

Puedes usar este código que personalicé:

```
$('#rut').inputmask({
    mask: '9{1,2}.9{3}.9{3}-(K|k|9)',
    casing: 'upper',
    clearIncomplete: true,
    numericInput: true,
    positionCaretOnClick: 'none'
});
```

Donde las propiedades son:

- **mask**: La máscara o patrón equivalente al formato de un RUT.
- **casing**: Se le asigna `'upper'` para convertir la K a mayúscula.
- **clearIncomplete**: Para borrar lo ingresado si no cumple con la cantidad de números/letras de `mask`.
- **numericInput**: Comienza la escritura de derecha a izquierda.
- **positionCaretOnClick**: Para posicionar el cursor de escritura donde se haga click y poder editarlo fácilmente.

**EDIT:**

Para prevenir que `clearIncomplete` borre los RUT que finalizan con K, cambia el orden del valor de mask:

```
mask: '9{1,2}.9{3}.9{3}-(9|k|K)'
```